# How to get started with LFS system

Tags: linux

I want to develop an OS using Linux from Scratch and Linux Kernel. I am currently using Windows 10 Pro. Do I need to install a Linux distribution like ubuntu on my computer side by side. Or I can install ubuntu app package on Windows 10 from Microsoft Store by enabling 'Windows Subsystem for Linux' to develop my OS. Does the latter serve all the capabilities required to develop an OS?

Comment: The traditional approach to LFS requires creating & mounting real partitions, which WSL can't do, but it ought to be possible to modify the instructions to do much of the work in that environment (though obviously unable to run it for real at the end since you couldn't make the partitions). How much will that be a problem for you? That is, what is your goal in making this system? Further, how confident do you feel about making those modifications on the fly? I suspect, given this question, not enough for it to be plausible to carry this out, but I could be wrong - be realistic, though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Checking the [How to Build an LFS System](http://www.linuxfromscratch.org/lfs/view/stable/chapter01/how.html) section of the Introduction Chapter, you might notice:

> The LFS system will be built by using an already installed Linux distribution (such as Debian, OpenMandriva, Fedora, or openSUSE).

and

> As an alternative to installing a separate distribution onto your machine, you may wish to use a LiveCD from a commercial distribution.

Checking [Host System Requirements](http://www.linuxfromscratch.org/lfs/view/stable/chapter02/hostreqs.html) in Preparing the Host System chapter you will find a series of tools that are required. *Are they available in Ubuntu app? Or could you install them?*

Another important note you can find in [Creating a New Partition](http://www.linuxfromscratch.org/lfs/view/stable/chapter02/creatingpartition.html) section of the Preparing the Host System chapter

> Like most other operating systems, LFS is usually installed on a dedicated partition. The recommended approach to building an LFS system is to use an available empty partition or, if you have enough unpartitioned space, to create one.

I think that if you are an experiences Windows, Linux and LFS user ... all of this notes can be easily addressed, however the official documentation doesn't seem to refer to support of build the LFS system from windows.

**If I can give my advice it will be:** use a virtual machine where you can install a linux distribution and have enough partitions for your to play with while building the LFS system. If something goes wrong you can just throw all away without messing up with your current system. Once you have more experience and successfully installed LFS using the official procedure you can try again with your original plan.

Comment: How much space do you think should i reserve for my partition? Is 25 GB enough

Comment: My question is: Does the latter serve all the capabilities required to develop an OS?